# Activiti mailtask can't send email

Tags: java, email, gmail, activiti

Relatively new to activity; can't seeem to get the mailtask working.

I have the properties below in the activiti-custom-context.xml file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email
>   to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
>       Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
>       Nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

activiti-custom-context.xml properties:

```
<property name="mailServerHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<property name="mailServerPort" value="465" />
<property name="mailServerUsername" value="jwalsh24793@gmail.com" />
<property name="mailServerPassword" value="*******" />
<property name="mailServerUseSSL" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not accept connections without TLS on port 465. You need to connect with TLS on port 587 to send an email.

You should change the port to 587 and add the following property:

```
<property name="mailServerUseTLS" value="true" />
```

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587                                                                                                                                 Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:   More or less the same thing happining

Comment: What happens when you do `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from a Windows command line?

Comment: So the connection itself can be made. My first thought is that your account is not set up for access from third party apps. You can configure this in your Google account settings. It is possible that changing this setting does not show immediate results so you may have to wait a bit. [Here's a link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).

Comment: I've checked the settings already they're fine . I've double checked username and password completely out of ideas.

Comment: So the account settings allow third party apps to connect? Also, earlier you said: `More or less the same thing happening`. Is the nested exception the same or different? Can you add the email you are trying to send to your question? Maybe there's something wrong there.

Comment: ive changed the to email a few times already .. Seems exactly the same apart from the exception differences above.